# Pronunciation of rebut

Tags: pronunciation

According to the Mac OS X's built-in dictionary app, the pronunciation of the word "rebut" is "rəˈbət". It is also the case on [this site](https://vocabulary-words.com/rebut/).

Shouldn't it be "rɪˈbʌt" instead?

Comment: I agree that the first syllable should have /ɪ/, not /ə/. I don’t think this is a case of the archephoneme /ɨ/ (as in _roses_ or _enough_). The second syllable is just a matter of transcription, though. /ʌ/ never appears in unstressed syllables and /ə/ never in stressed ones, so some (American) systems consider /ʌ/ the stressed variant of /ə/ and write them both as /ə/.

Comment: The built in dictionary you’re referencing is probably the New Oxford American Dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The "weak vowel merger": unstressed /ɪ/ often can be /ə/

In fully unstressed syllables, many English speakers don't have a clear distinction between /ə/ and /ɪ/. This has been called the "weak vowel merger". Most transcriptions of American English include the weak vowel merger, and generally transcribe the merged vowel as /ə/.

There are a few contexts where /ɪ/ is typically transcribed even in American English, though, like in the ending *-ic* as in the word *static.* I'm not to what extent this is predictable from the phonological context. In the context of Australian English, which is also supposed to show this merger, Cox and  Palethorpe (2018) say "/ɪ/ is typically retained in suffixes
like *-ish, -ic, -ism, -ing,* and /ɪ/ often still occurs when the
following consonant is postalveolar or velar but this could
possibly be considered allophonic (or free variation) e.g.
*paddock, stomach, beverage, manage*" ([p. 89](http://sst2018.unsw.edu.au/SST_proceedings/SST_2018_Proceedings_Rev_A_IDX.pdf)).

Another complication is that some speakers who have this merger do use somewhat different qualities on average for word-final and non-word-final /ə/, and the word-final quality is retained even when a consonant like /z/ or /d/ is added by inflection. For speakers with this kind of "Rosa's" vs. "Roses" distinction, non-word-final schwa tends to be phonetically closer/higher than word-final schwa.

### The complementary distribution of /ə/ and /ʌ/

In primary-stressed syllables, many English speakers don't have any distinction at all between /ə/ and /ʌ/. (Other speakers do report distinguishing stressed /ə/ and /ʌ/, e.g. in *just* "only" /ˈdʒəst/ vs. *dust* /ˈdʌst/.) If we assume that non-primary-stressed syllables containing /ʌ/ always have some kind of secondary or minor stress, then /ə/ and /ʌ/ are in complementary distribution for these speakers as long as we specify the stress pattern of a word.

This can be analyzed in different ways. One common way is to say that the phoneme /ə/ is phonologically restricted to unstressed syllables. But we could also say that /ə/ and /ʌ/ are not in fact distinct phonemes for these speakers.

Even if we don't actually adopt that viewpoint as a matter of technical analysis, the complementary distribution of /ə/ and /ʌ/ in the accents of these speakers means that we can unambiguously transcribe the phoneme /ʌ/ with the symbol "ə". Dictionary authors might choose to do this to reduce the number of unfamiliar symbols in their transcription scheme. I think that the symbol "ə" is more widely recognized than the symbol "ʌ", and most dictionaries are designed for a non-expert audience.